# How do you set a textInput to readOnly in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, readonly, textinput

How do you set a `textInput` to `readOnly`? I have the sample code below:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'GrossPay')->textInput(['id'=>'GrossPay','readonly'=> true])?>
```

Comment: This is exactly how it should be done for `readonly`. Are you sure you are looking for `readonly` and not `disabled`?

Comment: i to want prevent the user from entering data into the textInput because the value (GrossPay) of that textInput can be calculated using Javascript.

Comment: Ok, so `readonly` it is. It works like in your example.

Comment: thank you. its working now.

Comment: the problem was the path of the file

Answer (score 13):

It's `readOnly` not **readonly** but it does not make a difference here.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'GrossPay')->textInput(['id'=>'GrossPay','readonly'=> true])?>
```

Comment: Actually, it's `readonly` as in [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-readonly-attribute). HTML attributes are not case sensitive anyway but it's good practice to keep them lowercase.

Comment: @Bizley. Realize that after answering, that's why edited after that.

Comment: @Ermene. That should work, no mistakes with your code too. Tested